# Angular1 Scope not sending data to controller

Tags: angularjs

Im doing an angular project to pass a form varible to different controllers. I'm a bit new to angular but after learning about rootscope i still havent solved this, the controler send data to the form but the for can send data to the controller, can someone please help. Below is my code;

```
form:
  <form ng-submit="start()">
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-divider">Select Subjects</div>

    <label class="item item-input item-select">      
    <div class="input-label icon icon-left ion-book">
      Subject 1
    </div>
    <select ng-model="sub1">
      <option selected>ENGLISH</option>
    </select>
  </label>



    <label class="item item-input item-select">   
   <div class="input-label">
      Subject 2
    </div>
    <select ng-model="exam.sub2">
      <option>MATHEMATICS</option>
      <option selected>LITERATURE</option>
      <option>ECONOMICS</option>
        <option>GOVERNMENT</option>
        <option >PHYSICS</option>
        <option>COMMERCE</option>
        <option>ACCOUNT</option>
        <option>GEOGRAPHY</option>
        <option>BIOLOGY</option>
        <option>CRS</option>
        <option >CHEMISTRY</option>
    </select>
  </label>


Controller:
app.controller('setCtrl', ["$scope", function(c){
    c.start = function(){
       console.log = c.exam.sub2
    };

}]);
```

Thanks in advance`enter code here`

Comment: ng-submit is mal-formed  should be  `<form ng-submit="start()">`

Comment: Thanks Weijian, however the function connects properly. the challenge is to get the "$scope.exam.sub2" model, parse it to the scope in the controller and log the value to the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing is the exam object in your scope to begin with.

```
app.controller('setCtrl', ["$scope", function(c){
      c.exam = {};   // object to hold your form values   
      c.start = function(){
        console.log( c.exam );
      };

}]);
```

your HTML inputs should be

```
<select ng-model="exam.sub1">

<select ng-model="exam.sub2">
```